# Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу в Java

Tags: java

Найти максимальное расстояние между точками в двумерном пространстве.

Массивы заданы следующим образом:

```
x dd 10, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1
y dd 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 3, 2
```

Провальная попытка решения:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {2,5,6,8,9,0}; 
        int[] y = {4,9,5,17,1,12}; 
        double[] result = new double[x.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            result[i] = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x[i] - y[i]));
            System.out.println(
                "Difference is " + 
                (Math.abs(x[i] - y[i])) +
                " Sqrt is " + result[i]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы говорите о точках двумерного пространства. Где они здесь? Я вижу только два одномерных массива

Comment: я так полагаю из этих точек и нужно создать двумерный массив. Я пыталась это сделать (через 2 цикла for), но максимальная точка не выводилась

Comment: Еще раз. Опишите как из двух линейных массивов получить массив двумерных точек? Сколько в итоге должно получится точек? `x.length == y.length` или `x.length * y.length`?

Answer (score 3):

Если всё же нужна Евклидова метрика, и точка определяется `(x[i], y[i])`, то вычисляйте расстояние между парами точек c **разными** индексами:

```
maxdist = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++)
   for (int j = i + 1; j < x.length; j++) 
   {    
      dist = Math.sqrt((x[i] - x[j)*(x[i] - x[j) + (y[i] - y[j)*(y[i] - y[j));
      maxdist = max(dist, maxdist)
   }
```

Comment: внутренний цикл наверное через y должен быть?

Comment: @Dred Нет, если я правильно понял смысл входных данных, и длины массивов обязаны совпадать